# Magento2: Need help to create custom export

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, csv, export

I'm creating a custom module(multi-vendor) where i need to create one feature where admin can export the product details(CSV) data along with vendor details (which is assigned to some specific product).

I have all the tables available working only trucked in this feature...

find the points below I want to achieve..

**1. Export product & sales details for the selected vendor**

**2. Export Vendor/Vendors for selected products with sales**

Comment: any body have Idea about this...

Answer (score 2):

I have created a Admin Grid using Ui-Component.

Edit in your Ui-Component file where  Admin Grid Show

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \view\adminhtml\ui_component**

Add this code to add button in Admin Grid

***Ui-ComponentFIleName.xml***

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">

    <item name="import" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">import</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
    </item>

    <item name="export" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">export</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export</item>
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
    </item>

</item>
```

**Now create a File that Export or Import Data. File Name must be same as you defined in Ui-Component file**

```
  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>

  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
```

File path must be like this

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \ Controller \ Adminhtml \ [Controller_name] \ Exportdata.php**

***Exportdata.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\[module_name]\Controller\Adminhtml\[Controller_name];

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class Exportdata extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $_locationFactory; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \[vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\locatorFactory $locationFactory // This is returns Collaction of Data

    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
       $this->_locationFactory = $locationFactory;
       $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR); // VAR Directory Path
       parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        $name = date('m-d-Y-H-i-s');
        $filepath = 'export/export-data-' .$name. '.csv'; // at Directory path Create a Folder Export and FIle
        $this->directory->create('export');

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();

        //column name dispay in your CSV 

        $columns = ['Col-1-name','Col-2-name','Col-3-name','Col-4-name','Col-5-name','Col-6-name','Col-7-name','Col-8-name','Col-9-name',];

            foreach ($columns as $column) 
            {
                $header[] = $column; //storecolumn in Header array
            }

        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $location = $this->_locationFactory->create();
        $location_collection = $location->getCollection(); // get Collection of Table data 

        foreach($location_collection as $item){

            $itemData = [];

            // column name must same as in your Database Table 

            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-1-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-2-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-3-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-4-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-5-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-6-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-7-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-8-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-9-name');

            $stream->writeCsv($itemData);

        }

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder

        $csvfilename = 'locator-import-'.$name.'.csv';
        return $this->_fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);

    }


}
```

Now you can Click on the Export Button and see your .csv file Downloaded below.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply but I hope it will help someone else
In Magento 2 its quite simple. (refer to sales/order module)
in your ui component
you need exportButton under container name="listing_top"

```
     <exportButton name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
```

updates sales_order_grid by your module keywords and the export is done

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override uicomponent file sale_order_grid.xml in your module and create corresponding admin controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <exportButton name="export_button" class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToCsv</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToXml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="customcsv" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">customcsv</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom CSV</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">routefrontname/export/gridToCustomcsv</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
</listingToolbar>
```

`

for complete code check [my module](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/OrderGridExport)